Qualitative question: can the code matching the given patterns be made significantly faster if being written in pure C?
I made some code in Mathematica that I compiled in C. It involves operations such as looping inside While, custom random sampling from particular distributions, and working with 2D tables: many times extracting the elements, adding/removing rows, or modifying existing rows.
Could you please tell me if in principle, keeping the same algorithm, these operations may be made significantly (by a factor > 2) faster if rewriting the code in pure C and importing inside Mathematica using library link? I have a feeling that Mathematica is not so efficient in working with the tables in the manner specified above, even if compiling this code.

Hm. Adding/removing rows would be a bit problematic also in C. So the first thing you should think about is whether you can avoid that somehow. It is somewhat difficult to tell which data structure would serve your needs best. While loops typically don't have any penalty in Compile. If you need repeated calls to the compiled routine that repeatedly modify a given array, then Compile induces several copy operations that could be avoided by passing the array as reference via LibraryLink. So, overall it is hard to tell whether you will get a significant speed-up in C.

One advantage of doing it with LibraryLink is that you can use a customized random number generator. For example, xoshiro256+ served me very well in sampling random double precision floating point numbers. (I forgot how much faster it was compared to the Mathematica's random number generator, but IIRC, it was quite a bit faster; and was a lot faster than the standard number generator in the C++ standard library.)

@HenrikSchumacher: Thanks! I will think about it. But from your experience, do you know how fast multiple joining/deleting rows is in pure C(++) compared to Mathematica+C? It may be that even this possible speedup would be sufficient to me.

"But from your experience, do you know how fast multiple joining/deleting rows is in pure C(++) compared to Mathematica+C?" To be honest, I typically avoid that at all cost. Maybe storing ypu data row-wise in a doubly-linked list (i.e., in a does the trick for your application. (It probably would if you do not need fast random access to the rows.). C++ has plenty nicely containers. You could use a std::list<std::array<double,n>> if the size n of the rows is known at compile time or a std::list<std::vector<double>> otherwise.

If you do need fast random access to the rows, then maybe a std::unordered_map<key_type,std:: array <entry_type,n>> or std::unordered_map<key_type,std:: vector<entry_type>> does the job.
